# How to get code as a string from Babel node during traverse

Tags: javascript, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree, traversal

In the below code, is it possible to get the whole string representation of the AST node which would in this case return the `window.alert('asdf')`?

```
const ast = parse("window.alert('asdf')")

let preloadCode = ""
traverse(ast, {
  CallExpression: function(path) {
    // path.node.toString() ??
  },
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Each AST node returned by `@babel/parser` has a `start` and `end` properties pointing to it's location in the source code. You can use those to slice the source for the original string.

```js
const { parse } = require('@babel/parser');

const source = '1 + 2 + 3';
const ast = parse(source);
const node = ast.program.body[0].expression.left;

console.log(source.slice(node.start, node.end)); // → '1 + 2'
```

Comment: This answer most correct and best for performance

Comment: Can't comment on performance but `path.toString()` as suggested in @Eugene's answer is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-generator

Try this:

```
const { default: generate } = require('@babel/generator');

module.exports = () => ({
    visitor: {
        Identifier: (path, state) => {
            console.log(generate(path.parent));
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: one problem is @babel/generator will not honor the original code, e.g., in this example, it will always add a trailing semicolon in the end even if the original code doesn't have one. Is there a way to get the original code? or that information is lost during parsing?

Comment: Only answer that actually works if you don't have the original source, e.g. auto-generated nodes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[@babel/traverse](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-traverse), version 7.18.3

Just use `path.toString()`:

```
const ast = parse("window.alert('asdf')")

traverse(ast, {
   CallExpression: function(path) {
      console.log(path.toString());
   },
})
```

Found it [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9855)

Answer (score 1):

There is a method
https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-babel-core/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.element.babel-core.traverse.NodePath.prototype.getSource

```
const ast = parse("window.alert('asdf')")

let preloadCode = ""
traverse(ast, {
  CallExpression: function(path) {
    // path.node.toString()
    path.getSource() 
  },
})
```

Comment: How did you know or get that link? When I read the official Babel API documentation, I don't see them mentioning it either. And even when I "Search google" using the keyword "Babel-core API Document" I get no results containing that link. If possible please share how you did it. Thank you very much.

Comment: When I run the code, I get the error "const code = this.hub.getCode();
                   
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getCode')"

Comment: Here is my code: https://jsbin.com/niqehubexa/1/edit?js

Comment: I don't know if this answer ever worked, but it definitly doesn't work in 2022 with `7.17.8`.

Comment: `getSource` not working for me either, the `generate()` solution works just fine

Comment: `getSource` does not work with "@types/babel__traverse": "^7.18.3"

Answer (score 0):

If writing a plugin using babel >= 7.22.5 you can do this:

```js
export default function () {
  return {
    visitor: {
      CallExpression(path, state) {
        const { node } = path
        const { code } = state.file

        console.log(code.slice(node.start, node.end))
      }
    }
  }
}
```